# JavaScript code wont run on machine but does in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script, from my previous question. I tried running it but it won't work. There isn't any console message as well. It does conflict with something in console called lstr.js (I think it is chrome related), the code works fine in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc0ouvsb/) but not on my machine.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link'),         // add a class to the links and get them all
  contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content');  // same with the content blocks

    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {                        // loop through the links to add the event listeners
      var link = links[i];

      // add event listener
      link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        // reset color and hide content:
        for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
          // number of links should match number of content
          links[a].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
          contentDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
        }

        // set colour of clicked
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';

        // show clicked content
        document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("href").substring(1)).style.display = 'block';
      })
    }
```

Comment: `window.onload = function() { ...YOUR CODE HERE... }`

Comment: is this inside a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: You will have to show us your HTML as well. Have you even loaded the script?

Comment: @NelsonYeung It is in fiddle

Comment: @robertklep How can I make sure it loads after the page has been loaded and not before that?

Comment: Move the script at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that in a function and then do

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    nameOfYourFunction();
});
```

So in the end, your could would look like

```
function attachEvents() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link'); // add a class to the links and get them all
    var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content'); // same with the content blocks

    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { // loop through the links to add the event listeners
        var link = links[i];

        // add event listener
        link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        // reset color and hide content:
        for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
            // number of links should match number of content
            links[a].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
            contentDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
        }

        // set colour of clicked
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';

        // show clicked content
        document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("href").substring(1)).style.display = 'block';
        });
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    attachEvents();
}
```

The code is OK except you ought to check if `links.length === contentDivs.length`

Comment: I get a error saying ` Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: You're missing one or more of the elements for which you're setting the `.style` property. Please provide your HTML as well so we can assist you better.

Comment: [here](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/ZyzNBw) , Sorry took the time to reproduce.

Comment: Your `contentDivs` variable is empty because your HTML is a bit wrong. Look at your HTML at line 91.  
You have `class="row " class="content"`, that should be just `class="row content"`.

Comment: Thanks but now when I click any button, all rows disappear. I want to show each on its click.

Comment: Seems like it says ` Cannot read property 'substring' of null` I am presuming it is because I might have many other a half tags or something else?